# Vue js : window.addEventListener ne se trigger pas

Tags: vue.js, addeventlistener

My problem is that I am trying to get an access token from Spotify, but my window.addEventListener("message, function() {...}") is never triggered. Refer to the code below:

```
          mounted(){
    this.$nextTick(function() {
        function login(callback) {
            var CLIENT_ID = 'd3ebae5610894ca48c9f66794214252b';
            var REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:8080/spotify';
            function getLoginURL(scopes) {
                console.log('url')
                return 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=' + CLIENT_ID +
                '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(REDIRECT_URI) +
                '&scope=' + encodeURIComponent(scopes.join(' ')) +
                '&response_type=token';
            }
            var url = getLoginURL([
                'user-read-email'
            ]);
            var width = 450,
            height = 730,
            left = (screen.width / 2) - (width / 2),
            top = (screen.height / 2) - (height / 2);
            var w = window.open(url,
                'Spotify',
                'menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,status=no, width=' + width + ', height=' + height + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left
            );
            window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
                var hash = JSON.parse(event.data);
                console.log(JSON.parse(event.data))
                if (hash.type == 'access_token') {
                    callback(hash.access_token);
                }
            }, false);
        }
        var loginButton = document.getElementById('btn-login');
        loginButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
            console.log('click the button')
            login(function(accessToken) {
                console.log(accessToken)
            });
        });
    })}
```

Comment: Welcome, Caelou, to Stack Overflow. This is officially an English-only site for a global audience. Both answers and questions should be in English, so please post your questions in English. Imperfect English is fine, if it is just understandable. You can edit this post, for instance. Official policy: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/

P.S. You can of course try to find French speaking sites, as well :-)

Comment: Approximate translation:
"My problem is that I am trying to get an access token from Spotify, but the event listener for `message` is never triggered. Refer to the code below:"

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/200987

Comment: I change my message
Sorry for the post in french ^^'

Comment: That's because your `onMessage` listener is not bound to the window you opened using `window.open`. You should probably be doing `w.addEventListener` since you're storing that window object in the `w` variable.

Comment: I tried but when I store event.data its still empty